# Possible duality in proving "there exists unique" statements

Tags: linear-algebra

I have just done my first rigorous linear algebra course. Throughout I noticed that  we were proving lots of "there exists unique" statements. For the "there exists" bit you would use linear independence and for the "unique" bit you would use spanning. I found this quite odd because being linearly independent is a "unique" statement and being spanning is a "there exists" statement, so I'd have thought it would be the other way round? E.g. every function from a basis extends uniquely to a linear map is proved in this way.

Why would exists statements be used for uniqueness and vice versa rather than linear independence=> uniquness statements and spanning=> exists statements?

Is there some sort of duality going on? Because there is a unique expression for vectors there is some well-defined way to use them?

Comment: Could you summarize the steps of the proof that you're referring to?

Comment: Your observation might be related to the fact that a linear map is injective if and only if its adjoint is surjective, and surjective iff its adjoint is injective.